# DynamoDB NodeJS DocClient scan fails silently and intermittently?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Two developers have spent an entire day trying to determine what's going on here.  I realize fully that it's vague, but I'm putting it out there as we've spent all day on it.

We have an app that has used MongoDB and we are transitioning to DynamoDB.  We are trying to connect to a remote DynamoDB database. The lead developer was able to get the problem code to work on his machine, in a remote location. Two other developers took his code and tried to run it within the firm.  The following scan (below) fails silently 95% of the time.  No error, no timeout is returned.

The lead developer was offsite, so we thought of proxies, connections, etc.  We've tested it with Mac, with Windows (the lead uses Windows), as well as with a mobile hot spot with both Mac and Windows, to see if it was the firm's network connection.  Nothing worked.

The following code is where it goes wrong

```
this.docClient
            .scan(params)
            .promise()
            .then(data => {
                console.log('data received', data);
                resolve(data.Items);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log('error from scan', err);
            });
```

The call to `scan` never arrives at `then` nor at `catch`.

Very sporadically -- once out of 25 tries -- it works.

The `params` passed to the call are good.

The credentials are up to date.

The credentials are loaded from a shared credentials file as per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/loading-node-credentials-shared.html

When the following code is put right before the `scan`, the credentials are what they should be, but it makes no difference.

```
const credentials = new AWS.SharedIniFileCredentials({profile: 'default'});
AWS.config.credentials = credentials;
```

I know it's not much to go on, but any help would be appreciated. If not a possible solution, then perhaps things to investigate. We are at a complete loss.

Comment: Any progress on this? I'm facing the exact same situation

Comment: Sorry, I moved on from that long ago...never did resolve it.